# Way to properly escape user input which gets run by shell_exec() in PHP?

Tags: web-application, php, unix

I have the following script:

```
$user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
// If there is a way, I want to escape it here.
shell_exec("php some_file.php $user_input");
```

Is there a way to properly escape the `user_input`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) safely quotes a value (including escaping quotes in the name, etc) so that it can be used as an argument in a command string passed to a shell.

```
$user_input = $_POST['user_input'];
shell_exec('php some_file.php '.escapeshellarg($user_input));
```